# How to transform one row of a multilevel column dataframe into a regular dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, transform, multi-level

I have the following dataframe (constructed as below):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None,columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Apple','Banana','Orange'],['Data1','Data2','Data3']]),index=[1])
df.loc[:,:] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

>>>     Apple                   Banana                  Orange
        Data1   Data2   Data3   Data1   Data2   Data3   Data1   Data2   Data3
1       1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9
```

I want to transform this dataframe into the following dataframe (constructed as below):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=['Data1','Data2','Data3'],index=['Apple','Banana','Orange'])

>>>         Data1   Data2   Data3
Apple       1       2       3
Banana      4       5       6
Orange      7       8       9
```

I am trying to find the most pythonic way to make this transformation!  I have looked into transformations, swapping axes etc... but not sure if this is the right route to take.  I want to avoid having to rebuild the dataframe, but rather to just transform it with one or as few lines of code as possible.  Thanks!

Also!  As a side note, I could not figure out how to input the data directly into the first dataframe at the time of construction (as you can see I had to add it afterwards).  What structure should this data take in order to input it directly at the time of construction.  I tried multiple variations of lists and lists of lists etc...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None,columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Apple','Banana','Orange'],['Data1','Data2','Data3']]),index=[1])
df.loc[:,:] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

print(df, '\n\n')

df = df.T.unstack()
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()

print(df, '\n\n')
```

**Output:**

```
  Apple             Banana             Orange            
  Data1 Data2 Data3  Data1 Data2 Data3  Data1 Data2 Data3
1     1     2     3      4     5     6      7     8     9 


       Data1 Data2 Data3
Apple      1     2     3
Banana     4     5     6
Orange     7     8     9
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reorder or change a little bit the columns or the rows, you can explicitly create a new DataFrame out of the input one:

```py
new_index = df.columns.levels[0]
new_columns = df.columns.levels[1]

new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[[df.iloc[0][(n, c)] for c in new_columns] for n in new_index],
    index=pd.Index(new_index),
    columns=new_columns,
)
```

The result is:

```bash
        Data1  Data2  Data3
Apple       1      2      3
Banana      4      5      6
Orange      7      8      9
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I did state that I wanted to avoid having to rebuild the dataframe.  It does not feel like a pythonic solution.